# Last Name Appearing as XXXX on Spain Schengen Visa (No Last Name in PassPort)

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

I recently got my Schengen Visa from Spain and I don't have surname, so the name appearing on my passport is XXXX, ALOK KUMAR KRISHANAMURTH (the space for last "Y" was not there; my Given name on passport is Alok Kumar Krishanamurthy).

As people noted here, usually Schengen repeats names twice when there is no surname and this is the first time my name is appearing as XXXX,

In my previous Schengen Visas from France, Netherlands, Italy and Denmark, they gave my name as ALOK KUMAR KRISHANAMURTHY, ALOK KU..Shall I contact Consulate General of Spain in Mumbai why my last name is appearing as XXXX, and for missing "Y" in given name

Answer (score 4):

You surely can contact them and see if that is standard protocol for their visa officers, if it is then I doubt they will change it.

As for the missing character, they simply ran out of space. The Schengen code dictates the layout of the visa and they must cut out some characters from names if it interferes with the security features of the sticker.

Answer (score 1):

Contacted Spanish Embassy and they were fine with this as my surname is missing, they said XXXX shows that my surname is missing.